# C# Get last day of previous month given a month and year

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to create a method that returns me a DateTime object.

This date should be the last day of the previous month (month is given by me).

Example:

**Month:** january (1)

**Year:** 2019

**What I need:** 31/12/2018

This is what I have

```
   public DateTime getLastDayPrevMonth(int month, int year)
        {
            DateTime date = new DateTime();
            date.Month == month;
            date.Year == year;
            date.AddMonths(-1);
            date.Day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year,date.Month);

            return date;
        }
```

but it returns the error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: instead of `date.Month == month` you want `date.Month = month` (same for Year)

Comment: That returns another error :  `Property or indexer 'DateTime.Month' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
public DateTime GetLastDayPrevMonth(int month, int year)
{
    return new DateTime(year, month, 1).AddDays(-1);
}
```

This creates a new DateTime Object for the first day in the given Month/Year. Then it subtracts one day off of the first day of the month, leaving you with the last day of the previous month.

Answer (score 4):

you can get `Current Date` like

```
var CurrentDate= DateTime.Now;
```

and first day of `Current Month`   like

```
var FirstdayOfThisMonth= new DateTime(CurrentDate.Year, CurrentDate.Month, 1);
```

and you can add `-1` that will return last day of `previous month` like

```
var lastDayOfLastMonth = FirstdayOfThisMonth.AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: Except that you should in genral use `.Today` instead of `.Now`

Comment: yes sir but both are giving same result any other reason for using today instead of now thank you?

Comment: @ArunPratap there's no need for `CurrentDate` at all, if you'd look at OP's question.

Comment: @BoredomOverload yes brother but stack overflow is not a code writing service i have described how op can do that thank you